# Bar over/under integral symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I try to typeset bar over/under integral symbol with

```
\overline\int,\underline\int
```

But the line looks too long, any solution?

Comment: these are in unicode: U+2A1B and U+2A1C respectively.  as such, they should be in the stix or xits fonts, or other fonts supporting unicode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do (not in script styles)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\tint{\mathop{\mathpalette\tb@int{t}}\!\int}
\newcommand\bint{\mathop{\mathpalette\tb@int{b}}\!\int}
\newcommand\tb@int[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\int$}%
  \if#2t%
    \rlap{\hbox to\wd\z@{%
      \hfil
      \vrule width .35em height \dimexpr\ht\z@+1.4pt\relax depth -\dimexpr\ht\z@+1pt\relax
      \kern.05em % a small correction on the top
    }}
  \else
    \rlap{\hbox to\wd\z@{%
      \vrule width .35em height -\dimexpr\dp\z@+1pt\relax depth \dimexpr\dp\z@+1.4pt\relax
      \hfil
    }}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\tint_a^b f(t)\,dt=\bint_a^b f(t)\,dt
\textstyle
\tint_a^b f(t)\,dt=\bint_a^b f(t)\,dt
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$$\mathop{\smash{\hspace{4.44444pt}\overline{\hspace{-4.44444pt}\int}}\vphantom{\int}}
\nolimits^b_{\hspace{-4.44444pt}a}$$
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{paper}
\usepackage{STIX}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[ \upint\limits_{a}^{b} f(x) \ \text{d}x \ \ \ \lowint\limits_{a}^{b} f(x) \ \text{d}x \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding a few words wouldn't hurt.

Comment: And no you should not be using `\text{d}` here at all try `\itshape \[ \int \text{d} x \]` oops!  Use `\mathrm{d}` (there are a lot of people who does not understand what the `\text` command is for.

Answer (score 0):

For typing the upper and lower Darboux integrals, you could use

```
\[\overline{\int_{a}^{b}}f dx = \underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f dx\]
```