# \mathop spaces on \intop limits

Tags: math-operators

I use `\intop` from `esint` package and it behaves different with limits when included in `\mathop`.
It is declared as:

```
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{'001}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esint}
\begin{document}
$$ \mathop{\intop}_A^B  + \intop_A^B $$
\end{document}
```

Notice different placement of limits. How can it be done with `\mathop` and limits placed like without it? I need `\mathop` for constructing `\int` with dash, double dash and etc.

[image]

Comment: The usual trick is to print the dash, then back up and use `\int\limits`. See, for instance, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211132/4427

Comment: Flowing this link, I saw where I made a mistake. It was enough to add `\mathop` on dash and I putted it on all symbol. Thanks egreg!

Comment: egreg,folowing your example there still exist problem if you try to put limits with  `\limts`. Example `$$\tint\limits_{aaa}^b+\mathop{\tint}\limits_{aaa}^b+ \tint_{aaaa}^b $$`. Than you need to put `\mathop` if you want `\limts` and they do not look right.

Comment: How can I know what `\tint` is?

Comment: `\tint` is from example where you added a link.