# Recentering \bar over to account for integral alignment

Tags: math-mode, accents, bar

I'm trying to write an integral with upper and lower bounds denoted with over- and under-bars respectively. The issue is that because the integral is slanted, it makes it hard to line up the symbols correctly. `\underaccent` works beautifully (maybe accidentally) to line up the letter and the bar, but `\bar` puts the accent too far to the left. See below

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{accents}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{My Integral}
    \[
    \int_{\underaccent{\bar}{c}}^{\bar{ c}} x(c_j) dF(c_j)
    \]   
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Image of bar not quite working]

It seems like there should be a way to move the bar over... but my attempts to recenter the bar using added white space were foiled by math mode's removal of spaces. I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please always provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example, a smal complete document, beginning with  `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211101/bar-over-under-integral-symbol?rq=1

Comment: @jsbibra the linked question seems to be asking about putting bars and underbars on the integral symbol itself. This one seems to be about alignment of the bars and underbars which are placed on the _limits_ of the integration.

Comment: Please see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$` … `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: Thanks. I've been lurking for years, but I guess there are some things you only pick up by doing. How does the question look now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sansmathaccent` package (which in a modern distribution is already loaded by default by `beamer`) corrects the default bad placement of math accents for sans-serif letters, see [Bad positioning of math accents for the `beamer` standard font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4192/82917). However, the `accents` package re-implements the math accents, thus destroying the effect of `sansmathaccent`; in order to avoid this, the `accents` package can be loaded with the `single` option. To try and correct the effect of `\underaccent` one may insert some kerning, such that `accents` does not try to shift the `\bar` in the "correct" (from its point of view) position:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[single]{accents}
\newcommand*{\ubar}[2][0.5]{\underaccent{\bar}{\mkern-#1mu #2 \mkern#1mu}} % optional argument for fine tuning
% \usepackage{sansmathaccent} % shouldn't be necessary nowadays

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Accents}
\[
\bar{c} \quad \ubar{c} \quad \int_{\ubar{c}}^{\bar{c}} x(c_j)\,dF(c_j)
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the notation should mean.

Anyway, there are much simpler examples to see that this does not depend on the integral sign.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\[
\bar{c}+\underaccent{\bar}{c}
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

\[
\bar{c}+\underaccent{\bar}{c}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The fact is that the font used for letters in math mode is not tailored for being used in math, so the internal mechanism fails to properly move the `\bar` over the characters.

You get better results with `arev`:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{arev,arevmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\[
\bar{c}+\underaccent{\bar}{c}
\]   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're very fussy about the placement, you can use, also in your code, `\skew`:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{arev,arevmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\[
\skew{2}\bar{c}+\underaccent{\bar}{c}
\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your original example:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\[
\int_{\underaccent{\bar}{c}}^{\skew{3}\bar{c}}x(c_j)\,dF(c_j)
\]   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(don't forget the thin space in front of the differential).

[image]

Comment: I love palindromes: rep 798897 `:-)`  But that won't last long `:-D`

Comment: @campa Thanks! https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53359757#53359757

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\mybar}[1]{\bar{#1\hphantom{\:}}\mkern-4mu}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Accents}
\[
\int_{\underaccent{\bar}{c}}^{\mybar{c}} x(c_j)\,dF(c_j)
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That nonslanted *`d`* is sooo dirty :P.

Comment: @manooooh There are different schools of thought on it, so I left it as the OP wrote it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator

Comment: Thanks. This looks great aesthetically. I haven't used `\hphantom` before, but from my reading this makes a hightless space about 2 mu long to recenter the bar, then reduces the kerning so that the integrand isn't too far away. Am I missing any nuances?

Comment: @manooooh I deliberated about whether I wanted to get into that--trust that that's not what it'll look like in the final version :P

Comment: @campa meantime upvoted it :)

Comment: @MDRicks See campa's answer. It is the correct way to go.

Comment: Looks like I was too hasty in endorsing. Thanks!